# Webepage with extension .html having PHP codes vulnerable?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, security

Does changing the `.htacces` file to allow the programmer to have **PHP** codes in an HTML file (extension `.html`) compromise with the security of the page?

Is that the reason why files with any **PHP** scripting are given the extension `.php`?

Comment: Why down-rate the question? Isn't this is portal for asking questions whose answer we don't know. At least answer the question and then down-rate

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you haven't already. To answer your comment-question: no, some things are considered off-topic.

Comment: I think this question is important especially since it deals with the topic of security and PHP.  This question should be addressed especially for those new to PHP by those who've been using it longer and can speak from their experience concerning this matter.

Answer (score 2):

No. It does not yield any security problem if the file is interpreted and executed as a php file. You can even make any extension like ".asp",".jsp" anything you want. Furthermore this may sound a more secure way since an attacker sees the extension and thinks that it is an asp file.

However in my opinion it is not a good practice and may make development more confusing. I think if it is a php file the extension should be .php

If your desire is to provide security You should check url rewriting and hiding the extension. This way is a more convenient approach.

Answer (score 2):

Actually changing file endings of PHP files is rather dangerous. I experienced some problems first hand:

- Moving your project to a new server may cause the webserver to lose your configuration
- In a rather complex Apache configuration there may be multiple domains to get to your project you did not see in the first place; and one of these configurations may ignore your trick
- A misconfiguration of your webserver may render your clever trick useless (e.g. by using a default configuration)
- Other programmers may confuse your PHP files for HTML files

If one of these cases happen, any programming included in your PHP file can now be read by everybody. If there are configuration settings in your PHP file (DB connections, etc.) or some common programming mistakes (`print $_GET['search'];`) every attacker will now about them.

If your really want to keep your HTML file-ending, consider mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, having your files containing PHP scripts bear .html extensions provides more security, not less. This kind of security, known as "security by obscurity", affords a small measure of protection.  When a malicious hacker comes across an HTML page, s/he may  assume that the page was produced by HTML rather than being the output of a page containing a PHP script. However, if the hacker is sophisticated, s/he could verify whether you run PHP on your server by checking header info returned by the web server.  It's a good idea to set the php.ini setting `expose_php = Off` to avoid exposing PHP in the header information; see [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php).

If you use a .htaccess file or are able to modify your web server configuration settings,  it will impact performance by having all HTML files parsed by the PHP interpreter, including those pages that contain pure HTML. Sending pages that don't require PHP parsing is undoubtedly a wasted effort, but the amount of time involved is reputedly insignificant.  If you can modify the settings in your web server's config file, that's preferable since using a .htaccess file may cause your website to perform a little slower.

This kind of security is insufficient in itself to provide optimal security.  You still must regard all form data as possibly tainted and validate it.  Know what your form values should be and test for those values. The best security involves multiple layers of protection.

See the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php) for more ideas about "security by obscurity".  Note, that page does not recommend URL rewriting as a security measure, although it is an option. One should have  a very good understanding about URL rewriting since the subject is far from trivial.

> "... it is easy to make mistakes when configuring mod_rewrite which can
>   turn into security issues." (See [Apache Week, mod_rewrite](http://www.apacheweek.com/issues/02-02-01))

However, if you neglect to set `expose_php = Off` in your php.ini file the URL rewriting may not really hide the PHP as you might suppose.  If you run a php script containing this line:

```
print_r(get_headers($url,1));
```

you could get back some very revealing info, as the following partial result shows when I set $url to a page at one of my favorite sites:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Server] => nginx/1.6.2
    [Date] => Thu, 18 Dec 2014 09:59:06 GMT
    [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [Connection] => close
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.5.11-2
```

Comment: "In security engineering, security through obscurity is the use of secrecy of design or implementation to provide security. Security through obscurity is discouraged and not recommended by standards bodies. A system relying on security through obscurity may have theoretical or actual security vulnerabilities, but its owners or designers believe that if the flaws are not known, then attackers will be unlikely to find them." says Wikipedia ;)

Comment: "In general, security by obscurity is one of the weakest forms of security. But in some cases, every little bit of extra security is desirable." -- http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

Answer (score 1):

The only thing security related that you can add to `.htaccess` is user authentication. Beyond this, there is nothing that `.htaccess` can provide that will enhance the security of your application.

Do not rely on `.htacess` gymnastics for security purposes.

If you are porting over an existing website and doing it in stages, then it makes sense to use the same URL as those that might be bookmarked or referred to by other areas of your application; in this case you can use .html

If possible, try to use redirection and you *can* do that using `.htaccess`; but in some cases (for example, if you are trying to convert an existing file that is the target of a POST form into PHP) adding a redirect will make the form unusable as the payload will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will keep that in mind. But I didn't want to do that for security purposes. I just wanted to know if doing that is a good practice or not. Also, does that hurt my security rather than enhancing it in anyway?

Comment: It does not add much value in terms of security, and it only makes sense if you are porting an existing application. Beyond that there is not much more value it can add to the project.